# HTTP Header key allowed characters

Tags: http, http-headers

I have checked different documents for HTTP header key allowed characters. I haven't found any concrete results like these are characters that are not allowed? Can anyone please help me to find out which are the valid characters allowed in the HTTP header key as per specification?

Answer (score 1):

```
header-field   = field-name ":" OWS field-value OWS
field-name     = token
token          = 1*tchar
tchar          = "!" / "#" / "$" / "%" / "&" / "'" / "*"
                 / "+" / "-" / "." / "^" / "_" / "`" / "|" / "~"
                 / DIGIT / ALPHA
                 ; any VCHAR, except delimiters
```

References:

- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.2
- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.2.6

Comment: what is the mean of 1*?

Comment: @john, it means at least 1, and no upper limit.

Comment: What is the mean of any VCHAR in "any VCHAR, except delimiters"?

Comment: That is part of a comment, you don't need that. You should have the tools now to find out what VCHAR is by following those links and search around! But the line that starts `;` is ignored.

Comment: For the Header key now understood, Thank you. I was also checking header value it also confusing to me. I am still not able to understand it for the header value https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.2

Comment: tell me what part was confusing, and i might be able to tell you what is is / where its definition is

Comment: field-name     = token
     field-value    = *( field-content / obs-fold )
     field-content  = field-vchar [ 1*( SP / HTAB ) field-vchar ]
     field-vchar    = VCHAR / obs-text

     obs-fold       = CRLF 1*( SP / HTAB )
                    ; obsolete line folding
                    ; see Section 3.2.4

Comment: I understand some but it's a combination of all things so I can't relate to them.

Comment: Well, the BNF format that describes syntax is pretty well defined. I'm willing to step through it with you one step at a time, or perhaps open a new stack overflow question and dive in.

Comment: Created new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69493006/http-header-value-allowed-characters